# How to workaround an CachedConnectionManager error on JBoss with JRuby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jboss, jruby, jndi

I am having an issue deploying an JRuby Rails application into JBoss, using JNDI to manage database connections.
After the first request I have this error:

```
[CachedConnectionManager] Closing a connection for you.  Please close them yourself
```

I think this is because JBoss uses a connection pool and expect that rails (jruby) release the connection after each use, what is wrong, because rails (ActiveRecord) has its own connection pool.

I've tried to call

```
ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
```

after each request, in a `after_filter`, but this haven't worked.

Does somebody have some idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this issue?

Comment: My solution was to do not use JNDI, so I am now connecting directly to the database from ActiveRecord. It is not the desired way to solve the problem, but I have not found other way at that time.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having connection pool problems trying to run a Sinatra/ActiveRecord app in multithreaded mode in a Glassfishv3 container.  The app includes a "before" block with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` to force acquisition of a thread-owned connection, and an "after" block with `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!` to release that connection.

### Multi threaded mode

I have tried a great many variations of ActiveRecord 3.0.12 and 3.2.3, JNDI with a Glassfish connection pool, simply using ActiveRecord's connection pool, or even monkey patching the ActiveRecord connection pool to bypass it completely, using the Glassfish pool directly.

When testing with a simple multi-threaded HTTP fetcher, all variations I have tried have resulted errors, with a greater percentage of failing requests as I increase the worker threads in the HTTP fetcher.

With AR 3.0.12, the typical error is the Glassfish pool throwing a timeout exception (for what it's worth, my AR connection pool is larger than my Glassfish pool; I understand AR will pool the connection adapter object, and arjdbc will acquire and release actual connections behind the scenes).

With AR 3.2.3, I get a more ominous error.  The error below came from a test not using JNDI but simply using the ActiveRecord connection pool.  This is one of the better configurations in that about 95% of requests complete OK.  The error requests fail with this exception:

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (ConcurrencyError) Detected invalid hash contents due to unsynchronized modifications with concurrent users
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.keys(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1356)
    at ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.release(/Users/pat/app/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/lookup_service/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294)
    at ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.checkin(/Users/pat/app/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/lookup_service/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:282)
    at MonitorMixin.mon_synchronize(classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:201)
    at MonitorMixin.mon_synchronize(classpath:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.9/monitor.rb:200)
    at ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.checkin(/Users/pat/app/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/lookup_service/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:276)
    at ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionPool.release_connection(/Users/pat/apps/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/lookup_service/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstrac/connection_pool.rb:110)
    at ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler.clear_active_connections!(/Users/pat/apps/glassfish/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/lookup_service/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:375)
    ...
```

### Single threaded mode

Losing confidence in the general thread safety of ActiveRecord (or arjdbc?), I **gave up on using ActiveRecord multithreaded and configured warbler and JRuby-Rack do JRuby runtime pooling**, emulating multiple single-threaded Ruby processes much like Unicorn, Thin, and other typical Ruby servers.

In config/warble.rb:

```
  config.webxml.jruby.min.runtimes = 10
  config.webxml.jruby.max.runtimes = 10
```

I reran my test, using JNDI this time, and all requests completed with no errors!

My Glassfish connection pool is size 5.  Note the number of jruby runtimes is greater than the connection pool size.  There is probably little point in making the JRuby runtime pool larger than the database connection pool since in this application, each request consumes a database connection, but I just wanted to make sure that even with contention for database connections I did not get the time-out errors I had seen in multithreaded mode.

These concurrency problems are disappointing to say the least.  Is anyone successfully using ActiveRecord under moderate concurrency?  I know that in a Rails app, one must call `config.threadsafe!` to avoid the global lock.  Looking at the code, it does not seem to modify any ActiveRecord setting; is there some configuration of ActiveRecord I'm not doing?

Comment: I don't use my JRuby application in multi-thread mode, I am now using 5 runtimes.

Comment: @Douglas This doesn't seem to apply to your specific error, but I've discovered two issues: AR's connection pool is not threadsafe ("invalid hash contents due to unsynchronized modifications with concurrent users"); fixed by wrapping a couple methods with synchronize {}; need to test more and submit upstream.  Second issue is timeout under light load: v3.2.3 connection_pool.rb says "Sometimes our wait can end because a connection is available, but another thread can snatch it up first".  This has changed in (unreleased) version 4; not sure if the issue is fixed or not.

Comment: OK, Thank you by the consideration and helpful. This will be very useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails connection pool does hold connections open, even after they are returned to the pool, so the underlying JDBC connection does not get closed. Are you using a JNDI connection with activerecord-jdbc-adapter (`adapter: jndi` or `jndi: location` in database.yml)?

If so, this *should* happen automatically, and would be a bug.

If not, you can use the code in ar-jdbc and apply the appropriate connection pool callbacks yourself.

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/blob/master/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/callbacks.rb

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JdbcAdapter
  # This should force every connection to be closed when it gets checked back
  # into the connection pool
  include ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::JndiConnectionPoolCallbacks
end
```

Comment: This could be useful, but I use Oracle Enhanced JDBC adapter, and it don't release the connection. My solution was to do not use JNDI, so I am now connecting directly to the database from ActiveRecord